# SQL Aggregate functions with groupings

Tags: sql, aggregate, partition

I need to create some checks to make sure that students are enrolled in the correct courses with the correct number of units. Here is my SQL at the moment.

```
  SELECT StudentID
  ,AssessmentCode
  ,BoardCode
  ,BoardCategory
  ,BoardUnits
  ,sum(cast(boardunits as int)) over (partition by studentid,boardcategory) as UnitCount
  ,Count(boardcategory) over (partition by studentid)  as SubjectCount
FROM uvNCStudentSubjectDetails
where fileyear = 2015 
and filesemester = 1
and studentyearlevel = 11 
and StudentIBFlag = 0
order by Studentnameinternal,BoardCategory
```

This gives me the following info...

```
StudentID   AssessmentCode  BoardCode   BoardCategory   BoardUnits  UnitCount   SubjectCount
61687       11TECDAT        11080             A             2          11           7
61687       11PRS1U         11350             A             1          11           7
61687       11MATGEN        11235             A             2          11           7
61687       11LANGRB        11870             A             2          11           7           
61687       11ENGSTD        11130             A             2          11           7
61687       11GEOGEO        11190             A             2          11           7
64549       11TECIND        11200             A             2          10           7
64549       11SCIPHY        11310             A             2          10           7
64549       11SCIEAE        11100             A             2          10           7
64549       11MATGEN        11235             A             2          10           7
64549       11ENGSTD        11130             A             2          10           7
64549       11TECHOS        26501             B             2          2            7
64549       11MUSDRS        63212             C             1          1            7
45461       11ECOECO        11110             A             2          13           7
45461       11ENGADV        11140             A             2          13           7
45461       11HISMOD        11270             A             2          13           7
45461       11HISLST        11220             A             2          13           7
45461       11MATMAT        11240             A             2          13           7
45461       11PRS1U         11350             A             1          13           7
45461       11SCIBIO        11030             A             2          13           7
```

Note for the first student, I have a count of Category A subject Units (11 in total) He is only doing Category A subjects. For the second student, he has 10 units of Category A subjects, he is doing 1 Category B subject worth 2 units and one category C subject worth 1 unit. the final student just has 13 Category A units.

Now what I would really like is something like this...!

```
StudentID   Sum A Units Sum B Units Sum C Units Sum A Units + Sum B Units   Count of Subjects
61687          11           0           0                  11                 7
64549          10           2           1                  12                 7
45461          13           0           0                  13                 7
```

So I would like some aggregated functions with a student grouped onto only 1 row and the sum of his different units as separate fields. I would also like a field which sums the Category A and B Units and also a field which gives a count of the total number of subjects they are doing. I could then use this data to set up some warning messages if a student is not doing the correct number of A or B Units etc

I have played around with common table expressions, subqueries etc but am not really sure what I am doing and am not sure which is the correct way about getting the data in the form I want.

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: which dbms you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
STUDENTID,
SUM(CASE BOARDCATEGORY WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_A_UNITS,
SUM(CASE BOARDCATEGORY WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_B_UNITS,
SUM(CASE BOARDCATEGORY WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_C_UNITS,
SUM(CASE BOARDCATEGORY WHEN 'A' THEN 1 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_A_UNITS+SUM_B_UNITS,
COUNT(BOARDCODE) AS COUNT_OF_SUBJECTS
FROM (
    SELECT StudentID
    ,AssessmentCode
    ,BoardCode
    ,BoardCategory
    ,BoardUnits
    ,sum(cast(boardunits as int)) over (partition by studentid,boardcategory) as UnitCount
    ,Count(boardcategory) over (partition by studentid)  as SubjectCount
    FROM uvNCStudentSubjectDetails
    where fileyear = 2015 
    and filesemester = 1
    and studentyearlevel = 11 
    and StudentIBFlag = 0
    order by Studentnameinternal,BoardCategory
)
GROUP BY STUDENTID;
```

Wrapped your SQL statement in the solution, so that you can see what the solution does straight away.

Use SUM and CASE (i.e. SUM only when a condition is met).

Comment: Great - thanks so much - just what I was after. I had to change things a bit as I was after the sum of the units and most subjects are worth 2 units each, not the count. The sums now look like - SUM(CASE BOARDCATEGORY WHEN 'A' THEN BoardUnits ELSE 0 END) AS SUM_A_UNITS. I also had to remove the 'order by' from the SubQuery and use it after the group by statement at the bottom. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad I could assits, and that you were able to come to a final solution.